# Comparing String against Object in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I ran into a weird issue with comparing an object against a string in a laravel's blade file.

I have a variable that could be a string("N/A") or an object depending on the result from the DB query, and I have the following condition checks:

```
@if ($a_string_name == 'N/A')
```

If an object is returned, this condition will fail for most users and proceed to the else statement.

But for one specific case (I do not have enough information on how to reproduce this), this condition throws an error:

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() must return a string value
```

I cannot figure out what went wrong, or if this is laravel/browser specific issue.

PHP v7.4.22, laravel v6.0

Comment: This is an issue with your PHP code. When an object is used as a string, PHP tries to call a special function called __toString(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring. 
You could use `is_string($a_string_name)` instead of relying on string conversion.

Comment: @ryantxr ah, so this could possibly be due to the characters not being escaped correctly? But based on the source code from Illuminate\Support\Collection, __toString basically calls json_encode on the object, how would it return a non-string value that resulted in the error? I already confirmed that there are no special characters that needs special encoding...

Comment: You shouldn't rely on PHP to type juggle for you as it may lead to unintended consequences. First of all the `Collection::__toString` method essentially JSON encodes the collection result which may fail if there's values that can't be JSON encoded and is also an expensive operation. I don't think it's warranted in this case to use the same variable to sometimes be a string and other times be a collection especially when the times it's not a collection you just check if it's `N/A`. A `null` would work equally well and doesn't require casting to string

Answer (score 1):

From your question above I think you wanted to check if a variable is set or not with in given values. In your case try using ***@if(isset($a_string_name))***.

There are two PHP methods which we usually uses to check of our variables.

How do you check if a variable is defined in PHP?
The isset() function checks whether a variable is set, which means that it has to be declared and is not NULL. This function returns true if the variable exists and is not NULL, otherwise it returns false.

How do I check if a given variable is empty?
The empty() function checks whether a variable is empty or not. This function returns false if the variable exists and is not empty, otherwise it returns true. The following values evaluates to empty: 0.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this does not really resolve my case here. The variable will always be set and non-empty. The is_string method would probably suffice. However, the original concern is more with the reasons behind ```Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() must return a string value``` over a fix :).